# Regex find in text iframe and paste allowfulscreen attribute PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have text html:

```
<p>Is it my awesome text, and down I place my iframe with video, 
withot allowfullscreen attribute</p>
<p><iframe src="site.com/video.ogg" width="500" height="400"></iframe></p>
```

How I can with regex paste `allowfullscreen`?

```
<?php preg_replace('iframe', 'allowfullscreen'); ?>
```

But if `allowfullscreen` already exists, not paste.

Comment: where do you intend to do this copy/paste operation - in your source code or in a running webpage?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pyuAHi/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex from this example:

```
<?php

$no_fs = <<<HTML
  <p>Is it my awesome text, and down I place my iframe with video, 
    withot allowfullscreen attribute</p>
  <p><iframe src="site.com/video.ogg" width="500" height="400"></iframe></p>
HTML;

$has_fs = <<<HTML
  <p>Is it my awesome text, and down I place my iframe with video, 
    withot allowfullscreen attribute</p>
  <p><iframe src="site.com/video.ogg" allowfullscreen width="500" height="400"></iframe></p>
HTML;

    echo preg_replace('/(<iframe(?:[^>](?!allowfullscreen))+)>/', '$1 allowfullscreen>', $no_fs);
    echo "<br>";
    echo preg_replace('/(<iframe(?:[^>](?!allowfullscreen))+)>/', '$1 allowfullscreen>', $has_fs);
```

See the output in this [ideone.com snippet](https://www.ideone.com/4M0tZc).

With this regex you won't add `allowfullscreen` to iframes already having this attribute anywhere between `<` and `>`.